# Opposite of "capped at"

Tags: linguistics

If something like a score or a price is capped at 100, it means that if that score or price is higher than 100 it will be lowered down to 100.

Now my question is, is there an opposite expression which instead of lowering a higer value down, will lift a lower value up?

Comment: Capped doesn’t really mean “lowered down” it means prevented from exceeding.

Comment: That's a floor.

Answer (score 0):

**Prop up** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prop%20up))  to stop (something) from falling or slipping by placing something under or against it: to give help, encouragement, or support to (someone)

**Buttress** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buttress)) (figuratively) Anything that supports or strengthens.

**Level the field** ([Idioms by FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/level+the+field)) To make a situation or activity more fair and balanced by giving an extra advantage or opportunity to those who would normally be at a disadvantage, or by attempting to take away or diminish advantages, perhaps of one's adversary or competitor.

Answer (score 0):

Technical terms, not in general use: [saturation arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic)

E.g. many computer calculations are performed in 8-bit signed saturated arithmetic:

If a calculated result is less than -128, the result is clamped or saturated to -128

If a calculated result is greater than +127, then the result is clamped or saturated +127

Capped at = clamped or **saturated above** +127

… = clamped or **saturated below** -128

Verbosely one might say that “values >+127 saturate to +127 and values <-128 saturate to -128”

One usually talks about saturating to an interval such as [-128,+127).

Usually one saturates below zero or a negative value, and saturates above a positive value, so it is not necessary to say above/below.

But saturating/clamping above/below can be used.